# Module version is not available in the list of the installed modules

Tags: 8

I was using Drupal 6 and 7 before. I'm now trying with Drupal 8, but in admin/modules I don't see the module version.

> [image: screenshot from modules page]

Why don't I see the module version? Is that information that Drupal doesn't show anymore, do I need to change settings, or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On admin/modules, I can see the version of Drupal core modules, and third-party modules.

> [image: Drupal core modules]

> [image: third-party modules]

For third-party modules, Drupal will show the version only if it finds the necessary information in the .info.yml file of the module. In the case of the Honeypot module, this is what Drupal finds.

```
# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2016-03-11
version: '8.x-1.23'
core: '8.x'
project: 'honeypot'
datestamp: 1457671749
```

Without that, Drupal doesn't show the module version. For example, this is what Drupal shows for my custom module, which is not hosted on drupal.org.

> [image: custom module]

If you are using modules that aren't hosted on drupal.org, or you don't use Drush to download the modules, you will not see the module version. This also happens if you clone the module repository with Git instead of downloading the module archive from drupal.org.

Comment: It'll definitely be this - if you look closely at the screenshot you can see "Commerce" is installed, and the installation process for Commerce 2 bypasses the drupal.org method entirely

Comment: I guess that until the Composer repository implemented by drupal.org is not used, installing modules with Composer will cause this. Or at least, I hope they are going to add that meta information.

Answer (score 1):

It's there. You just need to click on expand button (beside the module description). Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It is for Core modules, but not for the contrib modules. I'm using Drupal 8.1.6. Maybe that is an issue for the Drupal Community. Thank you.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan Your answer is fine: The OP didn't say on which modules he didn't see the module version. I would had assumed he didn't notice the little narrow was clickable too.